# Change the file content dynamically while using spool

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, plsqldeveloper

I want to change the content in the file ABC. For example lets assume, In file ABC we are inserting a value in a database XYZ, I would like to replace XYZ with DEF with out opening the file manually. I would like to automate it. 
How could we do that in the above script? Is there any possibility that i could automate the process.

Comment: You could potentially use the `host` or `!` `SQL*Plus` command to call an operating system script that would do the replace.  In `unix`, that would likely involve the `grep` command.  http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_.21_and_HOST.3F

Comment: Cave, I am using sqldeveloper. I tried looks for host and i didn't find any related info for sqldeveloper. Please suggest an alternative.

Comment: `SQL Developer` appears to support the `SQL*Plus` `host` command.  You've tagged this for `PL/SQL Developer` which is a different IDE that is not from Oracle.  If you are actually using PL/SQL Developer, that tool may not support the `host` command.

Comment: Do you just want to supply a value at runtime? Have you looked at substitution variables, or even bind variables: either would involve changing your script to handle that to start with, of course.

Comment: Alex Poole, Yes when i run the file using spool, there it has to replace the database name in the file. I tried checking on substitution variables and these doesn't change the file content during run time.

Comment: @bin - no, as I said, you'd need to change the file once initially to allow that. After that running, the file (script) wouldn't change the file again.